# Neo4J: Automatically add node to manually selected index

Tags: indexing, neo4j

Sorry if this was already asked; I didn't find the answer or just didn't understand it..

I have a question regarding the indexes in the Neo4J release 1.9.3 (so sadly no labels yet). I plan on doing a small demo-application with superheroes and villains, which should basically just represent some heroes and whom they are fighting.

I'd like to add the superheroes and villains into dedicated indexes, so that I can parse them more easy.

I thought it's a good idea to use the auto-index feature but I'd like to specify which index the auto-indexing should use. Is this somehow possible?

So, in the end, I'd like to have something like;

> //auto-index superhero
>   CREATE (h1 { name : 'Batman', img : 'batman.jpg' })
>   CREATE (h2 { name : 'Captain America', img : 'ca.jpg' })
>   //auto-index villains
>   CREATE (v1 { name : 'Red Skull', img : 'rs.jpg' })
>   CREATE (v2 { name : 'Joker', img : 'joker.jpg' });

Or would you recommend to use the normal auto-index and just introduce something like "type: 'hero'"?

Answer (score 1):

There are only two auto-indexes: one for the nodes and one for the relationships. So you either use the node auto-index and you introduce the type property you mentioned (and query lucene with it), or you create two manual indexes.

Comment: When you configure the autoindexing, the indexes will be called `node_auto_index` and `relationship_auto_index`, see http://console.neo4j.org/ for an example using the node index.